# How to achieve polymorphism with singletons and static methods?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

So i have

```
    public class ApplicationConfig{

        public static ApplicationConfig getCurrentInstance(){
           //Something similar to this
        if(instance==null){
          FacesContext fc =FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            if(fc==null)
                return null;
            wac = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(fc);
        }
        instance =(ApplicationConfig)wac.getBean("appConfig");
          }
          return instance;
        }

    }
```

The way how the current Instance is retrieved differs from application1 and application2. Once I read it from spring, and once I use the plain singleton pattern.

Is there a way? both configs share some configurations - e.g.

```
public boolean isConfiguredForFoo() {
    return getCurrentInstance().getPropertyFoo().equals("foo");
}
```

**EDIT** so finally I want to be bascially able to do the following, or something like it:

```
ApplicationConfig.getCurrentInstance().isApplication1();
```

Where ApplicationConfig is an abstract or interface, application1 with it's implementation of getCurrentInstance and application2 with it's own implementation.

Furthermore: calling isConfiguredForFoo() finally calls getCurrentInstance. I cannot pull this function up because there is no implementation of getCurrentInstance in the abstract class and defining static abstract method is illegal. What way is there to keep all the isXXXXConfigured() together in one place and sticking to the DRY principle?

i have dependencies to jsf and spring in applicationConfig for application1 and no dependencies in application2. How can I use most functions from ApplicationConfig from Application1, only avoiding the crucial getCurrentInstance() function which accesses these dependencies?

Comment: Surely you'll need to pass a param from app1 and app2?

Comment: yes i'm passing in constructor. I could as well using setter getter.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: One of the motivations for Spring is that the singleton pattern does not allow inheritance. So let Spring manage the scope of your objects and don't use "the plain singleton pattern".

Comment: i updated my question.. well i can introduce spring - if use spring is the answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you have things in your ApplicationConfig which are not related to configuration.  You should take those out.  You could always have what you take out as members of ApplicationConfig.

Comment: alright we have 1 application with 6 different application configurations. All I am basically able to ask on applicationconfig is appConfig.getServerPort() and appConfig.isApplication5(). There's nothing else in it

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to archive?
But I suspect both applications retrieves the ApplicationConfig the same way.

- App 1: Spring with a `factory-method=getCurrentInstance`
- App 2: Manually calling getCurrentInstance();

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are doing, but the following *might* be useful:

```
 public abstract class AppConfig {

    private static AppConfig instance;
    static {
       if (whatever...)
          instance = new AppConfig1(); 
       else 
          instance = new AppConfig2();
    }

    public static AppConfig getInstance() {
       return instance();
    }   
 }
```

...

```
 if (AppConfig.getInstance() instanceof AppConfig1)
    ...
```

If you are reusing some code for the configuration sometimes in Spring and sometimes outside, maybe you are better off rewriting different classes for both cases.

Comment: the problem is that I cannot statically decide which application I'm on. The AppConfig class is used in 2 projects, and both projects make use of a third project which itself uses AppConfig

Comment: Just make 3 different AppConfig classes for the 3 projects (not subclasses of something, just 3 separate classes).  They can internally share some useful classes as members.  I don't think it's a good idea to use inheritance for configuration purposes.

Comment: but all projects must work on the same class. Lets say i have 3 classes: appconfig1, appconfig2, appconfig3. In Project 1 I refer to appconfig1, in project2 i refer to appconfig2 - but both must be the same. This is the idea of singleton - they must work on the same object

Comment: The projects are active at the same time?  If it's the case I'd just have one singleton class, with the strict minimum in it.

Comment: yeah I finally ended up doing that. But it's ugly, there is are dirty things in it I hate. E.g. figuring out whether this is an application with spring - if not e.g. object is null -> must be a normal object. Gross. Next time i'll keep my hands off the singleton and do everything with normal objects who have dependencies to the appConfig object.